# Is it a complement clause?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

> "In response to the growing pressure from people living in developing countries ***to be allowed to migrate and work in developed countries*** many governments have now imposed harsh restrictions on immigration."

I wonder what kind of clause of the bold part? I found a similar sentence in another website:[here](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/reduced-relative-clause-or-infinitive-complement.1798532/)

But I'm not sure that it's a complement clause. Please help me solve this problem

Comment: It's not a sentence.  It doesn't make sense, and the part you have underlined is a fragment noun phrase.

Comment: @michael_timofeev, I mean the quote part is a sentence. And the bold part is a clause.

Comment: Well, after your question was edited, it makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's a complement clause.  "[people] to be allowed to migrate ..." is the complement of the verb "press", so the underlying construction is a sentence "[people] press [authorities] to allow them to migrate ...". The complement clause was passivized.  Then, this sentence has been nominalized by converting the verb "press" into the derived noun "pressure".

I don't claim to understand the details.  It's a complicated example.  I don't see how to fit "growing" into the structure, though it's clear that it has the sense of an adverb "more and more" modifying "press".

Comment: Except it's not a sentence.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, I was answering the question that was asked.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth After the edit, it is now a valid sentence.

Comment: @Greg Lee, there's a comma between "countries"*,* "many governments".

Comment: Yes, that's a nice place for a comma.  When I read it aloud, I pause there.

Comment: @Elasthiccgirl Is this where you intended to post? I'll make a general comment: some of what were traditionally classed as phrases have been reclassified as clauses in some more modern grammars. You can spend a lot of time arguing that someone is wrong when they're actually using a different (and possibly more accurate/useful) set of definitions and analyses than the ones you were once taught.